# Compare a variable with a string in json

Tags: python, json, discord

I need to compare a variable to a string, and if the condition is true, do some action.
My JSON file looks like this:

```
with open('jsons/mutes.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
for i in data:
    if str(member.id) in data[str(member.id)]:
        await member.add_roles(role)
```

```
{
    "884021218808823839": "17.09.2021 1:17:09"
}
```

I need to check if the id(884021218808823839) of my user matches the id in the line(884021218808823839), if so, delete the line or do something.

Comment: Tried `if id_of_line in your_json_dict:`?

Comment: What code have you written to attempt to satisfy these requirements before posting here, in accordance with [ask]? What was the result? Can you include both here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you have any code written yet? If not, do you have any concept of how to work with JSON data in Python? If not, did you try putting *anything* into a search engine to try to find out something useful? Even something as basic as `python json`? Trying these kinds of things [is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: with open('jsons/mutes.json') as data_file:
        data = json.load(data_file)
    for i in data:
        if str(member.id) in data[str(member.id)]:
            await member.add_roles(role)

Comment: Is member an List of objects or a single object?